# Seaborn BarPlot invert y axis and keep x axis on bottom of chart area

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

In Excel, I can take a graph that looks like this:
[image]

And make it look like this:

[image]

By inverting the Y axis and setting "Horizontal Axis Crosses" to "max".

I would like to do this same thing in Seaborn. I can flip the y_axis using `.invert_yaxis()` but I am unable to keep the bars on the bottom of the chart like I can in Excel.

```
import seaborn as sns
barplot = sns.barplot(x='abc'
                      ,y='def'
                      ,data=df
                      ,ci=None
                      )
barplot.invert_yaxis()
barplot.figure
```

Which produces something like this:
[image]

How can I move the bars from starting at the top, to starting at the bottom?

I am using Python 3.6 and seaborn 0.7.1

My question seems similar to this one but this question is unclear and has no answer:
[Pyplot - Invert Y labels without inverting bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39070206/pyplot-invert-y-labels-without-inverting-bar-chart)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`seaborn.barplot` is a wrapper for `pyplot.bar` and you may use `pyplot.bar` to create the plot with an inverted yaxis and bars that range from the bottom of the chart to a lower value up the y axis:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"x":range(5), "y": [1,1.2,1.4,1.6,1.8]})

plt.bar(df.x, 2*np.ones(len(df))-df.y, bottom= df.y )
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.ylim(2,0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is the most confusing / counterintuitive chart I have seen in a long time.

Comment: (Not a criticism of your answer, obviously.)

Answer (score 6):

I found out that you can simply do:

```
plt.ylim(reversed(plt.ylim()))
```

which allows you to keep using Seaborn.